# How to run a cron job at every 5 hour interval

Tags: linux, cron, cron-task

How to run a `Cron` job at every 5 hour interval?

I've tried this

```
0 */5 * * * /path/to/script/script.sh (Not necessarily a shell script)
```

But the problem with this `expression` is it'll run every `5 hour` but the clock will reset at midnight `00:00:00` everyday.

**Explanation:** if the job executes at midnight `00:00:00` then following will be the execution timing

```
00:00:00, 05:00:00, 10:00:00, 15:00:00, 20:00:00
```

after `20:00:00` the job will execute at `00:00:00` which is `1 hour` earlier than specified.

But my requirement is the job should run at 5 hour interval and shouldn't get reset at midnight

So if the job starts at midnight `00:00:00` the following should be the executing order.

```
00:00:00, 05:00:00, 10:00:00, 15:00:00, 20:00:00, (Day 1)
01:00:00, 06:00:00, 11:00:00, 16:00:00, 21:00:00, (Day 2)
02:00:00 ...                                      (Day 3)
```

How do I achieve the following through `Cron`?
Any help would appreciated.

Comment: Reason for vote down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option from [this forum post on unix.com](https://www.unix.com/solaris/87000-how-define-every-5-hours-crontab.html) Run it every hour, and add to your script:

```
time_ct=$(cat /tmp/cron_time_ct)
if [ $time_ct -lt 5 ]
   then
     echo "Not yet time"
     time_ct=$((time_ct+1))
     echo $time_ct > /tmp/cron_time_ct
     exit
   else
     time_ct=0
     echo $time_ct > /tmp/cron_time_ct
fi
# rest of your task
```

I've done similar to do "every other monday" type logic. Running the script every monday and only allowing execution on every other one in the script.

Comment: Can you please explain this? and this is specific to shell script?

Comment: No. This goes in your `/path/to/script/script.sh` at the top. You want to kick that script of every hour, and this bit of script at the top will check if it's been 5 hours since the last run. If it has been, then it allows the rest of the script to execute, if not it hit's 'exit' and dies.

Comment: I've to change the `expression` to hourly basis? Like this? `0 */1 * * *`

Comment: Just `0 * * * *` to run at the top of the hour, every hour.

Comment: So all together it'll be like this? `0 * * * * time_ct=$(cat /tmp/cron_time_ct)
if [ $time_ct -lt 5 ]
   then
     echo "Not yet time"
     time_ct=$((time_ct+1))
     echo $time_ct > /tmp/cron_time_ct
     exit
   else
     time_ct=0
     echo $time_ct > /tmp/cron_time_ct
fi` `/path/to/script/script.sh`

Comment: Not exactly, no. The crontab line is `0 * * * * /path/to/script/script.sh` then `script.sh` is edited to include the code above. Like this new code resides in the script that is being executed by crontab.

Comment: But if the job is to run a `JAR` rather than a shell script then?

Comment: Now... that is a bit of a pickle. Option 1: Implement this logic in the jar (assuming you have the source code and all that). Option 2: Make a shell script that executes the jar, and stick this code at the top of that script. then the execution is like `Crontab every hour >>> NewSCript.sh >>> Jar file`. Not pretty, but totally reasonable.

Comment: Yeah, that seems convincing to me. Thanks.

Comment: Any Suggestion on making the wrapper script more generic? As the interval could be dynamic.